# enable stackdriver monitoring agent google container engine clusters on gci image

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

This describes how one would install the agent on a regular gce instance:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent

Previously the cluster ran on debian os nodes and we'd have the agent running to monitor cpu, disk space etc. now it's upgraded to kubernetes 1.4 and running on container-optimized os (https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/) the agent can't be installed manually.

I realise pods are monitored automatically, but that's only part of the picture.

I feel like I'm missing something here as this it'd be a big backward step for this not to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I've ran into the same thing several times. You have to switch back to the `container-vm` format in order to install the stackdriver agent.

`gcloud container clusters upgrade --image-type=container_vm [CLUSTER_NAME]`

That should flip it back. You can install the agent once the images flip. We're running 1.4.7 on the `container-vm` image and haven't seen any issues. Seems like overhead but not an actual step-back if that helps.

Comment: ok thanks. I guess full monitoring must be on it's way at some point for gci.

Comment: also container_vm is deprecated. not sure when it dissappears altogether : https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/resources/faq

Comment: It's not deprecated yet, they are just saying that they want to deprecate it. The only thing happing now is that it's not the default image. When it happens, it's a pretty easy flip to go back (hopefully they will have the agent issue resolved by then). Same command as above, just use `gci` as the `image-type`.